# Huge requests spikes but no record in nginx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I can see the huge spike of network requests

However, nginx shows no noticeable difference of requests amount for the time frame.

Does it mean there are requests bombing which doesn't go to nginx? (such as ping requests?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on size of packet that you sent to server.

> A correctly-formed ping packet is typically 56 bytes in size, or 64
> bytes when the ICMP header is considered, and 84 including Internet
> Protocol version 4 header. However, any IPv4 packet (including pings)
> may be as large as 65,535 bytes